# Adding Single image to CGContext background makes tile view on output

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

Currently I am developing a project by using CGContext to draw image on the specific path.

In my sample i have used a class file which is inherited from the UIView,

Inside the Draw override method, I am getting the UIGraphics.GetCurrentContext(), by using this I have drawn the arc of 0 to 360 degree,

The CGContext setFillColor has to be filled with the image, so i have used the below given code.

```
var image = UIColor.FromPatternImage(imageView);

context.SetFillColor(image.CGColor);
```

imageView contain a single image, but on the output screen the image get repeated for many times.

Sample to replicate this issue has been updated in this query.

Please download the sample from this [link](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-android/files/2300480/TestApp.2.zip)

Note: This question has been raised on [GitHub](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-macios/issues/4645)

They have said that this is the behaviour. When adding image on the background of CGContext we will get tiles of image on the screen.

Can any one help me to sort out this issue?

Thanks and Regards,

Selva Kumar V.

Answer (score 0):

As the link ([Apple Document](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicolor/1621935-colorwithpatternimage?language=occ)) said . During drawing, the image in the pattern color is tiled as necessary to cover the given area if you call the method  UIColor.FromPatternImage .So you can scale the size of image before you call the method .Refer to the following code.

```
public UIImage ScalingImageToSize(UIImage sourceImage,CGSize newSize)
  {

  if(UIScreen.MainScreen.Scale==2.0) //@2x iPhone 6 7 8 
    {

     UIGraphics.BeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, false, 2.0f);
    }

   else if(UIScreen.MainScreen.Scale == 3.0) //@3x iPhone 6p 7p 8p...
    {
     UIGraphics.BeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, false, 3.0f);
    }

   else
    {
     UIGraphics.BeginImageContext(newSize);
    }

   sourceImage.Draw(new CGRect(0, 0, newSize.Width, newSize.Height));

   UIImage newImage = UIGraphics.GetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

   UIGraphics.EndImageContext();

   eturn newImage;

  } 



   //. . .
    UIImage imageView = new UIImage("a0.png");
    UIImage newImage = ScalingImageToSize(imageView, new CGSize(200, 400)(the size you want));
    var image = UIColor.FromPatternImage(newImage); 
   //. . .
```